# ¿Cómo ejecutar un timeout esperando el evento anterior?

Tags: javascript

Se me ejecuta todo la vez después de un segundo en vez de ir de uno en uno, y querría saber como arreglarlo para que funciones correctamente

Código:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tierra.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        gameScene.addChild(tierra[i]);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Tendrías que dejar un ejecutable en un snippet como ejemplo para entender que quieres hacer, y así poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tu pregunta es mas de lógica, a como funciona, hay un truco para esto; y es sumarle los segundo que le corresponde esperar:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tierra.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        gameScene.addChild(tierra[i]);
    }, 1000 + (1000 * i));
}
```

Te coloco el ejemplo para fines practicos:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let today = new Date();
            console.log(`mirenme soy i ${i} , segundo ${today.getSeconds()}` )
 
        }, 1000 + (i * 1000) );
  }
```

Lo que quieres hacer tambien se puede hacer por promesas pero dependera de la logica anterior; por lo pronto de esta forma es sencilla y practica

---

Con promesas quedaría mejor porque esperaria efectivamente 1 segundo despues de ejecutarse la primera instruccion (variacion de [Francisco Romero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/148570/28035))

```js
function ejecutandoPromesas(longitud){
  if (longitud == 0){
    return 0
  }
  return new Promise(function (resolve , reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(longitud )
      resolve(ejecutandoPromesas(--longitud))
    },1000)
  })


}
console.log(ejecutandoPromesas(6))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que quería

Answer (score 6):

Si lo que quieres es que se ejecute **cada iteración del bucle con un intervalo de tiempo de un segundo entre ejecución** podrías crear una función que se fuera llamando a sí misma con un intervalo de 1 segundo mediante la función `setTimeout`.

Ejemplo:

```js
function ejecutarCodigo(iteraciones){
  setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Aqui tu código");
        
        if (--iteraciones) //Si es > 0, que siga llamando a la función
            ejecutarCodigo(iteraciones)
    }, 1000);
}

ejecutarCodigo(5);
```

donde 5 sería el número de iteraciones, `tierra.length` en tu caso.

---

En caso de que quisieras un **bucle infinito que se repitiera cada segundo** podrías utilizar la función **[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)**.

Ejemplo:

```js
setInterval(function() { 
      console.log("Aqui iría tu código"); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Pero eso se haría infinitamente y no siguiendo el bucle para poder usar el contador

Comment: @Juankaxx Vale, había entendido mal la pregunta. Pensaba que querías que se repitiera infinitamente. Déjame editar la respuesta.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Voy a editar la respuesta para dejar ambas opciones.

Comment: @Juankaxx He editado la respuesta para mostrarte una solución en la que se ejecutarían solamente la cantidad de iteraciones que tu quisieras con un intervalo de un segundo entre una y otra.