# ¿Por qué el valor *i* siempre es *5* - JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(i); 
     },i * 1000 );
    }
```

Buenas, en el siguiente trozo de código, el valor de *i* siempre es *5*, en el console.log(). ¿Por qué?

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta que te soluciono el problema como aceptada

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Con este ejemplo se vería aproximadamente lo que ocurre con la función.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
console.log(i);
 setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log('TimeOut: ' + i); 
 },i * 1000 );
}
```

Lo único que hice fue colocar un `console.log()` fuera de la función `setTimeout` y añadirle un `string` al que existe dentro de dicha función para diferenciar.

Si revisamos lo que nos escupe la consola podemos ver que primeramente se pinta:

```
14:55:01.689 0
14:55:01.689 1
14:55:01.689 2
14:55:01.689 3
14:55:01.689 4
```

Para posteriormente escupir:

```
14:55:01.691 TimeOut: 5
14:55:02.698 TimeOut: 5
14:55:03.690 TimeOut: 5
14:55:04.690 TimeOut: 5
14:55:05.696 TimeOut: 5
```

El tener activado el temporizador de la consola del navegador nos permite apreciar también en que momento se ejecuta cada salida por consola.

Revisando esto podemos ver que la función `setTimeout` tarda más en lanzarse pro primera vez que lo que tarda el bucle en recorrerse entero, por lo que esta cuando accede a la variable `i` ya se encuentra con valor 5.

Comment: creo que la pregunta va a explicar mejor el singlethread , el tiempo de compilacion ejecuta el for y coloca en el stack el setTimeout ya que es una funcion asincrona

Comment: Realmente si que se trata de un problema de monohilo y de cuando se ejecutan en la pila otros hilos de ejecución fuera del principal. Gracias por el aporte @JackNavaRow

Answer (score 12):

Lo mejor para entender lo que pasa es reproducir la ejecución manualmente:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // durante 5 veces ...
  setTimeout(function() {     // ... colocamos en la cola de eventos por tiempo...
    console.log(i);           // ... una función que imprime el valor de i ...
  },i * 1000 );               // ... con un segundo entre cada función.
}
```

Y un segundo después, con i valiendo 5 (que es cuando el bucle ha terminado), se imprime su valor.

Y un segundo después, con i valiendo 5 (que es cuando el bucle ha terminado), se imprime su valor.

Y un segundo después, ... bueno, ya sabemos lo que pasa.

Esto ocurre porque se ha creado una clausura de función: i es una variable externa a la función anónima que se le ha pasado a setTimeout, por lo que se queda en memoria con el último valor existente.

¿Por qué se comparte i entre las 5 funciones?, bueno, hay que entender que [el uso de `var` conlleva un comportamiento especial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1): El compilador "sube" la declaración al inicio del bloque:

```
//equivalente a tu código
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log(i); 
 },i * 1000 );
}
```

En cambio, si usases `let`, en cada iteración **estarías trabajando con una instancia distinta**:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 //en cada iteración se genera una variable i con un valor distinto!
 setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log(Date(),'->',i); // es una variable distinta para cada función
 },i * 1000 );
}
```

Otra solución, en caso de que no puedas usar let (no funciona en IE10), es usar lo siguiente:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

 setTimeout(function(param1, param2) { 
    console.log(param1, param2); 
 },i * 1000, 'Pasando 2 parámetros',i );
}
```

La función [`setTimeout` permite definir los parámetros](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) con los que será llamada la función *callback*:

> ```
> setTimeout(funcion[, retraso, parametro1, parametro2, ...]);
> ```

Comment: Me intriga saber (y nadie contesto) porque la ultima funcion no tarda 5 segundos en ejecutarse.. si el timeout de la ultima es 5000...

Comment: Tarda 5 segundos, pero quizá no te das cuenta porque la anterior tardó 4, la anterior 3... con lo que cada segundo que pasa tienes una escritura. He añadido un *timestamp* a lo que se muestra

Comment: Me desdigo.. tenes razon.. se ve que el problema fue donde yo lo probe..

Answer (score 11):

Para responder debes saber dos cosas:

- JavaScript es  [single thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/174922/28035), y <sub>[como lo explica nuestro Gurú Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243005/28035)</sub>, Javascript ejecuta todo el archivo  `.js` y las funciones asincronas la coloca en su ***cola de eventos***; es decir que el codigo ejecutado en primera instancia es `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ }` y en la ***cola de eventos*** de Javascript queda cinco veces `setTimeout(function() { console.log('TimeOut: ' + i); },i * 1000 );`

---

- Al declarar la variable tipo [**`var`**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/106067/28035) esta tiene otro tipo de alcance. por el cual el ultimo valor sera el #5, y al ejecutar el `setTimeout` desde la **cola de eventos** i ya tiene el valor # 5

```js
for (var i = 0; i< 5; i++){
}
console.log(i);
```

Modificare el código un poco , para fines practicos puedas entender del porque 5

```js
function ejecutatimeOut(){
    setTimeout(function() { 
      console.info(`TimeOut ${i}`);
      
   },i  * 1000 );
 
 }
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

}

console.log("valor de i=" , i); // la variable ya esta en 5
ejecutatimeOut()
ejecutatimeOut()
ejecutatimeOut()
ejecutatimeOut()
ejecutatimeOut()
```

La solución  a esta pregunta te invito a leer esta respuesta:

> [¿Cómo ejecutar un timeout esperando el evento anterior?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148566/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-un-timeout-esperando-el-evento-anterior/148576#148576)

Comment: Muy interesante, gracias por la corrección. Uno no pasa por aquí sin aprender algo nuevo :)

Answer (score 4):

Al declarar la variable con `var`, en el `for` se está sobrescribiendo su valor. Prueba con un `let`:

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(i); 
     },i * 1000 );
    }
```

Comment: Podrías añadir una explicación de porque funciona con `let` y no con `var`?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer una función que devuelva otra función.

Esta función recibe el argumento `i`, y se va transpasando a la función de adentro, aunque esa función, no recibe ningún argumento.

Por último, se le pasa el argumento para que esa función sea *generada*.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout( // La i se transpasa hacia abajo
    (function(i){ // ----------+
      return function(){ //    ‖
         console.log(i); // <--+
      }
    })(i), // Aquí se le pasa el argumento.
    i * 1000 );
}
```