# Tiempo de espera entre cada interacción de bucle for - jQuery

Tags: jquery, bucle-for, timeout

antes que nada comentar que ya he leído otras preguntas similares pero no han resuelto mi problema, entre ellas [¿Cómo ralentizar un loop for en javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352898/c%C3%B3mo-ralentizar-un-loop-for-en-javascript) y [¿Por qué el valor *i* siempre es *5* - JS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320720/por-qu%C3%A9-el-valor-i-siempre-es-5-js)

Cómo el código es muy largo compartiré la parte en la cual tengo el problema y una imagen con la descripción de que hace cada función o variable mencionada.

```
function updateHistory(url) {
            $(".history ul li", thisObj).remove();
                        
            if (settings.version == 1) {} else if (settings.version == 2) {
                //cuando llamo a la función borro la clase .row-wpr y desaparecen todas las filas del DOM
                $(".row-wpr", thisObj).remove();
                            
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    url: url,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //fijo el número de filas a agregar en 5
                        data.length = 6;
                        for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var rowNum = i;
                            var listVal = rowNum;
                            var songtitle = data[i].title;
                            var songtitleSplit = songtitle.split('-');
                            var artist = songtitleSplit[0];
                            var title = songtitleSplit[1];
                            //agrega al DOM una fila con el titulo de la canción (title), artista (artist) y un número (listVal)
                            $(".history-wpr", thisObj).append("<div class='row-wpr'><div class='history-cover' id='row" + rowNum + "'></div><div class='history-track-info'><div class='history-songtitle'>" + title + "</div><div class='history-artist-name'>" + artist + "</div></div><div class='rowNum'>" + listVal + "</div></div>");
                            //si se ha elegido mostrar las caratulas las obtengo con la función getImageList
                            if (settings.artwork == !0) {
                                getImageList(artist, title, rowNum);
                                } else {  //de lo contrario coloco un logo predefinido 
                                $('#row' + i, thisObj).css({
                                    "background-image": "url(" + settings.logo + ")",
                                    "background-size": "100% 100%"
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

[image: imagen DOM]

**Resumen del problema a resolver**

Esta parte del código lo que hace es mostrar las últimas 5 canciones reproducidas, cada vez que se llama a la función que realiza el update se borran las 5 canciones anteriores y se imprimen nuevamente las filas eliminando la última y poniendo en primer lugar la canción que se estaba reproduciendo antes del update.
*Las 5 filas se imprimen "simultáneamente"* (por la velocidad del bucle) como se muestra en la imagen.

**Que deseo ?**

Deseo *ralentizar el bucle* de tal manera que se muestre la fila 1 (con su imagen a la izquierda) transcurran 3 segundos y se muestre la fila 2 y así sucesivamente hasta completar las 5.

**Qué he intentado ?**

Como los datos del título, autor y número se obtienen con `$(".history-wpr", thisObj).append` y las imágenes se obtienen con la función `getImageList` *intenté poner una función `setTimeout`* en ambos lugares, sustituyendo ambas líneas de código mostradas arriba por estas:

Tiempo para título, autor y número

```
setTimeout(function() { 
$(".history-wpr", thisObj).append("<div class='row-wpr'><div class='history-cover' id='row" + rowNum + "'></div><div class='history-track-info'><div class='history-songtitle'>" + title + "</div><div class='history-artist-name'>" + artist + "</div></div><div class='rowNum'>" + listVal + "</div></div>"); },i * 3000 );
```

Tiempo para imágenes

```
setTimeout(getImageList(artist, title, rowNum),i * 3000 );
```

El asunto es que "i" siempre vale 5 (lo mismo que sucedía en otra pregunta relacionada que cité al comienzo), aún usando `let` en lugar de `var` que fue la solución que se brindó en en ese momento.
Por tal motivo se repite 5 veces los datos de la última canción y lo curioso que no se muestra ninguna imagen, desconozco el motivo ya que no da ningún error.

[image: image luego del cambio]

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionarlo y compartiré esta solución para todos aquellos usuarios que deseen ralentizar un bucle for en JQuery o JavaScript.

Para resolver este problema, debe usar el cierre: invoque inmediatamente la función a la que se llamará en cada iteración con "i" como param y `setTimeout` dentro de esta función. En este caso, el parámetro que pasó se almacenará en el alcance y podría usarse en la devolución de llamada de tiempo de espera:

```
for (var i=1; i<6; i++) (function(t) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    //hacer cualquier cosa con t (aquí va el código que quieres iterar)
    }, t*3000)
}(i))
```

Con este ejemplo se vería aproximadamente lo que ocurre con la función:

```js
for (var i=1; i<6; i++) (function(t) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(t);
    }, t*3000)
}(i))
```

Para mi caso particular tuve que eliminar un condicional que no es de importancia en mi código porque no logré obtener las imágenes poniendo dos SetTimeout independientes y la solución que funcionó fue esta:

```
function updateHistory(url) {
            $(".history ul li", thisObj).remove();
                        
            if (settings.version == 1) {} else if (settings.version == 2) {
                //cuando llamo a la función borro la clase .row-wpr y desaparecen todas las filas del DOM
                $(".row-wpr", thisObj).remove();
                            
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    url: url,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //fijo el número de filas a agregar en 5
                        data.length = 6;
                        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) (function(t) {
                            var rowNum = i;
                            var listVal = rowNum;
                            var songtitle = data[i].title;
                            var songtitleSplit = songtitle.split('-');
                            var artist = songtitleSplit[0];
                            var title = songtitleSplit[1];
                            //agrega al DOM una fila con el titulo de la canción (title), artista (artist) y un número (listVal)
                            setTimeout(function() {
                            $(".history-wpr", thisObj).append("<div class='row-wpr'><div class='history-cover' id='row" + rowNum + "'></div><div class='history-track-info'><div class='history-songtitle'>" + title + "</div><div class='history-artist-name'>" + artist + "</div></div><div class='rowNum'>" + listVal + "</div></div>"); 
                            getImageList(artist, title, rowNum);
                            }, t*3000)
                        }(i))
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```